# Get Twitter Link Images from API

Tags: twitter

If someone posts a tweet with a link, and Twitter pulls and image from that site, for example: https://twitter.com/MTCBATA/status/960972071890165760 is it possible to fetch that image via the Twitter API? It doesn't seem to be showing up in `entities`.

Comment: That image is from the Twitter Card attached to the URL shared in the Tweet. There's no card information in the Twitter API, so there's no way to get that image without yourself crawling the target URL for the twitter:image or og:image tag on the target site.

Comment: @AndyPiper that's basically what I figured, is there any indication within the API that the link SHOULD be crawled? Like that the included link has a `twitter:image` tag so I'm not crawling every single URL

Comment: No, there’s no card data associated with Tweet objects in the API, so no simple way for this to be discovered.